# How to pass a PHP variable to a link in the same page

Tags: php, html

I am a newbie in programming and this might be very basic. (I searched in the internet but can't find the solution).

**My case:**
In a HTML file, I am retrieving a url parameter by $_GET['s1'] and this is the code:

```
<?php $username=$_GET['s1']; ?>
```

I am successful in doing thing but what I need to do is to get the $username variable to be inside a link in the same page.

This link is actually a button in the same page. Once clicked, it will take you to another page. and its code is as follow:

```
<a href="http://www.mywebsite.com/AM/index.php/myusername_1 " id="btn_1_eed2a4ea6f9ab0ffcae6eced4295bd8e" class="css-button style-1"><span class="text">BOOK</span><span class="hover"></span><span class="active"></span></a>
```

I want to replace myusername in http://www.mywebsite.com/AM/index.php/myusername_1
with $username.

I might not be able to change the the button code as I am using a program called "optimizepress" to build this page. I can only insert the link of the button and insert a custom HTML or a shortcode anywhere in the page.

This page is to be given to my affiliates and I don't want to insert every affiliate's unique link in his duplicate of this page. I just want my affiliates' links to get generated automatically.

THANKS in advance

Comment: Please dont use raw user input. you are running a risk, that your website will be hacked. at least do a simple escaping like $username = htmlspecialchars($_GET['s1']); see http://php.net/manual/de/function.htmlspecialchars.php

Comment: @Umingo Isn't the problem on the landing page? That's where harmful code can be injected, not here where it only builds the URL.

Comment: if the landing page is called with ....firstpage.php?s1=<evil_html_code_with_js> then this page will output what ever the evil one wants.

Comment: Which is exactly the same thing you can do to any page from the console... The problem is when the bad code reaches the server, not the client.

Answer (score 1):

Simply echo it inside the HTML (I used a shortcode, but `<?php echo $username; ?>` still works):

```
<a href="http://www.mywebsite.com/AM/index.php/<?= $username ?>" 
   id="btn_1_eed2a4ea6f9ab0ffcae6eced4295bd8e" 
   class="css-button style-1">
     <span class="text">BOOK</span>
     <span class="hover"></span>
     <span class="active"></span>
</a>
```

If you might have some non-URL-safe characters, make sure to [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) the username first.

Comment: THANKS Shomz, to urlencode is to do this:

<a href="http://www.mywebsite.com/AM/index.php/<?= urlencode($username) ?>" id=.......

is this right? I already referred to the link page you posted.

Comment: Yes, that's what the code should look like exactly. You're welcome! :)

Comment: HI Shomz,
I tried but it did not work. This is the url I get after clicking the button: 
http://www.mywebsite.com/AM/index.php/<?php echo username; ?>

Comment: Are you sure it's the .php page and not plain HTML? Ah, now I see you said `In a HTML file`... It should be a PHP file running on a server (though the server can be "taught" to parse the HTML files as well, it's not recommended).

Comment: Aha now I see the point.
I even tried passing the url parameter to a PHP file but it does not pass it. This is what I tried:
<form method="get" action="reload-1.php">
<input type="text" name="username"
 value="<?php echo $_GET['s1']; ?>">
</form>

Can you suggest something to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1):

You can use following -

```
   <?php
   $username = htmlspecialchars($_GET['s1']); 

    ?>
```

And for your HTML Code do this -

```
<a href="http://www.mywebsite.com/AM/index.php/<?php echo $username; ?> " id="btn_1_eed2a4ea6f9ab0ffcae6eced4295bd8e" class="css-button style-1"><span class="text">BOOK</span><span class="hover"></span><span class="active"></span></a>
```

Comment: Please dont use raw user input. you are running a risk, that your website will be hacked. at least do a simple escaping like $username = htmlspecialchars($_GET['s1']); see http://php.net/manual/de/function.htmlspecialchars.php

Comment: @Hitesh, he is not right... Malicious code can't come from the server to the client (unless there is a serious problem in the server code, which is not the issue here), but the other way round.

Comment: In this case, I will not use htmlspecialchars. I thought I need to

Comment: @Shomz but this is a GET method, anyone can play with the URL right ?

Comment: @Hitesh Yes, exactly, but it's only used to generate another URL, no harm there. The problem is if the username check on the second landing page is not sanitized. GET on the first page becomes a part of the URL of the second page (which can be altered manually no matter how hard you try to sanitize the GET on the first page). Makes sense? If not, try to think of a malicious action here, and I'll show you why it's safe.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<a href="http://www.mywebsite.com/AM/index.php/<?php echo $username; ?>_1 " id="btn_1_eed2a4ea6f9ab0ffcae6eced4295bd8e" class="css-button style-1">
  <span class="text">BOOK</span>
  <span class="hover"></span>
  <span class="active"></span>
</a>
```

The PHP Preprocessor will replace the `<?php echo $username; ?>` with the content of the variable.